# Unable to identify the image causing error - PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file

Tags: keras, deep-learning

While training a NeuralNetwork model, I am getting the below error:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fd6342bdfb0>
```

I have updated the PIL version to the latest version. I am unable to point out which image file is causing the problem. All the image files used are JPG files.

The below is the code that I'm using.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True
                                  )
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(IMG_PATH_TRAIN,
                                                 target_size = (224,224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 shuffle = False
                                                 #class_mode = 'categorical'
                                                )

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(IMG_PATH_TEST,
                                            target_size = (224,224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            shuffle = False
                                            #class_mode = 'categorical'
                                           )
lr = 0.003
sgd = SGD(lr=lr, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

input_shape = (224,224,3)
inputs = Input(input_shape)

def set_model(base_model):
  x =  base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(82, activation='softmax')(x)
  base_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs= [x])
  batch_size = 32
  
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
  
  base_model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'],
                     loss_weights=[1,1,1],
                     optimizer= sgd,
                     metrics=['accuracy']) #, 'top_k_categorical_accuracy'])
  
  base_model.fit(training_set,
               steps_per_epoch=20991//batch_size,
               epochs=1, 
               validation_data=test_set, 
                             validation_steps=7456//batch_size, #test_samples // batch_size,
                             verbose=1)

  return base_model

base_model_inception = InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor = inputs)
base_model_inception = set_model(base_model_inception)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the size and the format of the images? There might be a chance that some of the images are not correctly formatted, for example RGB vs RGBA.

Also, if the images are read in the gif format, which is P, then the TensorFlow library will fail to convert it during the data generation, which could lead to the error.